# How to subtract the current figure from the previous figure in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

1. I have a simple select query below, now what I want is to have the cumulative balances by employee under cumtotal
2. A moving value difference which is achieved by subtracting the cumulative value in the month of Feb by Jan, example see below:

[image]

I do not want to use the domain function, I have enough of poor performance, I understand the answer to this are sub queries, this is where I’m trapped, I real need your help. Our pay as you earn works on cumulative basis, that is the reasons why I need this.

I will appreciate if can be done, unfortunately access does not work like excel, otherwise this is very thing in excel.

```
SELECT tblstaff.Id, tblstaff.FirstName, tblstaff.LastName, 
       tblstaff.JobTitle, tblpayslips.SalaryDate, tblSalaries.Gross,
       Sum(([tblSalaries].[Gross])) AS CumTotal, 0 AS Diff
FROM (tblstaff INNER JOIN tblpayslips ON tblstaff.Id = tblpayslips.EmployeeName) INNER JOIN tblSalaries ON tblstaff.Id = tblSalaries.Id
GROUP BY tblstaff.Id, tblstaff.FirstName, tblstaff.LastName, tblstaff.JobTitle, tblpayslips.SalaryDate, tblSalaries.Gross, 0
ORDER BY tblstaff.Id, tblpayslips.SalaryDate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName, 
       s.JobTitle, ps.SalaryDate, sa.Gross,
       (SELECT SUM(sa2.Gross)
        FROM tblSalaries as sa2
        WHERE s.Id = sa2.Id = s.Id
       ) as RunningTotal,
       0 AS Diff
FROM (tblstaff as s INNER JOIN
      tblpayslips as ps
      ON s.Id = ps.EmployeeName
     ) INNER JOIN
     tblSalaries as sa
     ON s.Id = sa.Id
ORDER BY s.Id, ps.SalaryDate;
```

If the `diff` is the difference from the cumulative sum, you can use a subquery and put the difference in the outer query.